# Los email generados con tablas para enviar por correo incrustan espacios en blanco entre las imágenes

Tags: android, app, gmail, outlook

Cuando genero un html con tablas para enviarlo por correo en *gmail app* para android siempre me mete espacios entre las imágenes.

En el resto de gestores de correo me funciona correctamente incluyendo en la tabla lo siguiente:

```
border-collapse:collapse;
mso-table-lspace:0pt;
mso-table-rspace:0pt;
font-size:1px;
line-height:0;
mso-margin-top-alt:1px;
```

¿Alguien conoce alguna solución?

Por favor, que no sea la de poner `display="block"` en las imágenes que eso ya no funciona.

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="" />
<title>Grandes profes grandes iniciativas</title>
</head>
<body> 
<!-- AVISO PUBLICIDAD -->
<table align="center" id="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:5px;"><font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Si no ves correctamente la newsletter, haz click </font> <font color="#000000" size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b><a href="url_redirect" style="text-decoration: underline;color:#000000;" target="_blank">aqu&iacute;</a></b></font></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- FIN AVISO PUBLICIDAD -->
<table align="center" width="700" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;font-size:1px;line-height:0;mso-margin-top-alt:1px;">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="url" target="_blank"><img src="imagen" width="700" height="103" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="imagen" width="700" height="681" alt="" border="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%23GrandesIniciativas&src=typd" target="_blank"><img src="imagen" width="700" height="43" alt="" border="0"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo del HTML del email?

Comment: Gracias. Me llevo peleando durante semanas. He intentado ver como lo hace Litmus PutsMail pero el código resultante no incluye nada especial, sin embargo, los envíos salen perfectos.

Comment: Gracias por añadir el código. Ahora no estoy en un ordenador donde pueda hacer tests, pero luego lo pruebo más tarde... o igual alguien consigue ayudarte antes :)

Comment: De nuevo muchas gracias. Es un placer encontrar gente como tú. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Al final buscando y buscando he encontrado una posible solución.
Incluir estos estilos en la página en el

```
<style type="text/css">
.ReadMsgBody {
    width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass * {
    line-height: 100%;
}
img {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}
a img {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-block-start:0;
    margin-block-end:0;
    margin-inline-start:0;
    margin-inline-end:0;
    padding-block-start:0;
    padding-block-end:0;
    padding-inline-start:0;
    padding-inline-end:0;  
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-block-start:0;
    margin-block-end:0;
    margin-inline-start:0;
    margin-inline-end:0;
    padding-block-start:0;
    padding-block-end:0;
    padding-inline-start:0;
    padding-inline-end:0;  
}
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Lo que hay que hacer es incluir la imagen dentro de un párrafo con los siguientes estilos:

```
<tr>
    <td style="font-size:0;line-height:0;">
        <div style="margin:0;font-size:0;line-height:0;margin-block-start:0;margin-block-end:0;margin-inline-start:0;margin-inline-end:0;padding-block-start:0;padding-block-end:0;padding-inline-start:0;padding-inline-end:0;">
                <p style="margin:0;font-size:0;line-height:0;margin-block-start:0;margin-block-end:0;margin-inline-start:0;margin-inline-end:0;padding-block-start:0;padding-block-end:0;padding-inline-start:0;padding-inline-end:0;"><a href="https://fundacion.atresmedia.com/nuestros-proyectos/mejora-educativa/grandes-profes/grandes-iniciativas/" target="_blank"><img style="display:block !important;line-height:0 !important;font-size:0 !important;" src="http://servidor.com/imagen.png" width="650" height="296" width="650" height="250" alt="" border="0"></a>
                </p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```